# Can't switch to database other than _system within Foxx

Tags: arangodb, foxx

I'm trying to dynamically generate databases/collections on application startup, in case they do not exist yet. This works fine when working with the `_system` database. The thing is that it seems not to be allowed when trying to switch to other databases. From the docs:

> **db._useDatabase(name)**
>
> Changes the current database to the database specified by name. Note
>   that the database specified by name must already exist.
>
> Changing the database might be disallowed in some contexts, for
>   example server-side actions (including Foxx).

Does this mean that Foxx applications can only create collections within the `_system` database? My manifest file sets the `isSystem` property to false. What is the meaning of such limitation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Foxx is included in one database context and has access to the collections there.
You can install Foxx apps in different databases.
f.E. you can run the following commands in arangosh to install the foxx app "example" in the database "myDB":

```
db._useDatabase("myDB")
fm.install("example","/example")
```

your app will than be reachable at (assuming standard configuration):

```
http://localhost:8529/_db/myDB/example
```

It is intentionally not possible to access a different database from within a Foxx app.

Comment: Great, I see there is ```--server.database``` option in ```foxx-manager``` tool, which I did not notice. Thanks!