# How to grant a task to execute a query?

Tags: security, task, arangodb, nosql

I need to run a continous task inside my ArangoDb, the database itself has the security turned on. When I post a task to the API end point, the task is registered but then on the error log I get the following:

> JavaScript exception in file 'undefined' at 3,75: ArangoError 11:
>   forbidden

No surprise about it... But how can I actually log a user from the @arangodb module?

Just in case, here is the code of my task:

```
    function() {
      const db = require('@arangodb').db;
      db._useDatabase("foo"); 
      db._query("LET now = DATE_NOW() FOR u IN wait FILTER now - u.time >= 300000 REMOVE {_key: u._key} IN wait"); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24934374/cant-switch-to-database-other-than-system-within-foxx) that states, the only other database Foxx can access is _system.

I'm assuming your example is not running in 'foo' and you're trying to jump over to a different database, which is forbidden.

If you want to have a single view of data in other database, you can publish REST endpoints in each database, with Foxx, and then from an external app call all of those REST endpoints, pulling in data from multiple databases.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I'm not using foxx, as I said, and I am not jumping from a database to another database. As the task is posted on the foo database and my query acts on a collection of that database. I am using this feature [link](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.1/Manual/Appendix/JavaScriptModules/Tasks.html)

Comment: Ah, when you mentioned the @arangodb module there I assumed it was in Foxx. If you are running this code from Node.js, have you looked at the [arangojs library](https://github.com/arangodb/arangojs) which is maintained by the ArangoDB team?

Comment: Yes David, I am running my node app on arangojs. I am trying to use the task feature of arangoDb, the link is in my comment above. This feature provide an api endpoint where I can post a JS function to be run on top of Arango internal V8 every x seconds. The fact is that I cannot find a way to authenticate that task to the database. Thanks for your interest

Comment: So you're using the Foxx Queue service and running tasks in it? Those tasks will still be bound to only be able to use the database they are in as well as _system. I use tasks as well and they can't get out of their database.